# [Carplay]: Crash of the main app at viewcontroller presentation while having the carplay app opened at the same time

Tags: ios, swift, uiscenedelegate, carplay, uiscene

I just implemented our new Carplay feature @Qobuz but I'm having a weird crash that I can't find an answer at.

**Scenario:**

- Having the carplay app opened and using the application on the phone at the same time, if I ever open a viewcontroller that is presented, the app crash at the end of the presentation
- IF the carplay app is not opened, then the exact same action won't crash the app.

**Context:**

- I'm having the crash on both simulator and device (currently running **iOS 14.2** simulator)
- I'm using UIScenes, one for the app, one for carplay. I believe, after multiple checks, that I implemented and configured correctly my scenes
- For the moment, I still keep the property *window* in my AppDelegate
- We have two versions of Carplay, one for iOS versions under iOS 14 and one for the iOS versions 14 and above. This means I put some `@available(iOS 14.0, *)` since our minimum versions supported is iOS 12.0

Here is the crashlog:
[image: Crashlog]

Here is the Info.plist Scene Manifest

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
<dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CPTemplateApplicationSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                <string>CPTemplateApplicationScene</string>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>${CARPLAY_SCENE_ID}</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).CarplaySceneDelegate</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
        <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>UISceneClassName</key>
                <string>UIWindowScene</string>
                <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                <string>${APP_SCENE_ID}</string>
                <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).AppSceneDelegate</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Hopefully one of you will work his magic to get me out of this :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is the action that causes the crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation, it appears the crash was not on our side but due to Instabug iOS SDK. They have been warned of the issues and corrected it in version 10.7.1 and I can confirm that our app has stopped crashing